# Create and send Hierarchical Data from flex to java

Tags: java, apache-flex, hierarchical-data, advanceddatagrid, dataprovider

I'm trying to create a Hierarchical Data Grid in flex using AdvancedDataGrid. The data is retrieved from a remote java object.
For project and requirement purposes, GroupingCollection is NOT an option.
So I'm trying to create a dataprovider just like the one shown in the first example in [this link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_07.html), on the java side and then send it to flex.

How do i create such a data structure in java?
Is there any working code as an example?

In all examples that I've seen the data is manually inserted just like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

In `flex`, you can set the `dataProvider` to some different data types. When you are working with `Java` for back-end and `flex` for UI, you should take in account the communication through `XML` as basic data representation. So, even if you want to use as `dataProvider` for your `AdvancedDataGrid` an `ArrayCollection` or an `GroupingCollection`, you will create this kind of data from an `XML` that is taken from the `RemoteObject`. I think searching on the web about this topic will help you.